# one plot, different xlim. how to solve?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

how to get three graphs on top of each other, that are from the same data frame?
i had the idea of shifting them all to x=0, but i'm not sure how to also shift the y values.

```
ax=M3.plot(y="Wirkleistung [W]")
ax.set_xlim(a,b)
bx=M3.plot(y="Wirkleistung [W]")
bx.set_xlim(c,d)
cx=M3.plot(y="Wirkleistung [W]")
cx.set_xlim(e,f)
```

like this it's three plots. but i'd like to have one plot to be able to better compare the datas.
thanks!!

Comment: Would you mind providing a minimal reproducible example?